# How to use Javapns to Support Apple's Enhanced Notification Format

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

Greetings,

I am creating a Java based server to create push notifications for Apple's iOS APNs service.  I have found Javapns on google code which seems to provide a simple basic framework to communicate with APNs, and which seems to be fairly wide used.

http://code.google.com/p/javapns/

However, reading Apple's docs, there is an "enhanced format" for notifications which supports "expiry" i.e. setting a time (well, in seconds) for a notification to expire if it hasn't yet been delivered.  I do not see any way to set this using Javapns, and I am unsure how the APNs service handles expiry of notifications if you do not explicitly set it.  So,

1. Does anyone know how to support the enhanced notification format of APNs specifically how to set the expiry?
2. Does anyone know how Apple handles notification expiry if it isn't explicitly set?
3. Does anyone have any suggestions that don't require me to start from scratch, as the server is currently functional as is?

Thanks in advance.

Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have recently made substantial contributions to the JavaPNS project, which lead to the release of JavaPNS 2.0 a few days ago.  That version provides full support for the enhanced notification format, including the ability to set your own expiry.

Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

Nice that you found the java library... to bad you didn't read the docs there.

I'll post some of the highlights below:

---

The existing code uses the 'Simple notification format' which does not return an error EVER.

See docs at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

I've tried updating to the 'Enhanced notification format' which is supposed to return an error, but I'm unable to get any errors back from the APNS. (also in the link above)

With the Enhanced format, the connection isn't being dropped immediately after sending data, but I'm not getting anything back from my socket.getInputSocket.read() call.

This issue will have to be tabled until I have more time to troubleshoot.

(Someone else commented)
Thanks a lot for looking into it. 
I got the same result as yours. Maybe it has something to do with Apple Gateway.

---

So... you could:
1) Build your own
2) Help improve the existing library
3) Try another library like: https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns
4) Do nothing

Comment: Where in the Javapns docs does it say anything about Enhanced format?  I certainly didn't see it.  The docs you provided a link to are Apple's, not Javapns.  There is a bug requesting support for it, but it had not yet been accepted or started when I submitted this question.  Obviously, I know they didn't currently support it, or I wouldn't have posted the question.  And what's with the snark?

Comment: Not reading any more, I decided to try Java-APNS instead.  It works, does expiration, and the author is far more helpful than javapns.  In my experience at least.

Answer (score -1):

Enhanced ios push [here](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns).
 To send a notification, you can do it in three steps:

**Setup the connection**

```
ApnsService service =
    APNS.newService()
    .withCert("/path/to/certificate.p12", "MyCertPassword")
    .withSandboxDestination()
    .build();
```

**Create and send the message**

```
String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("Can't be simpler than this!").build();
String token = "fedfbcfb....";
service.push(token, payload);
```

**To query the feedback service for inactive devices:**

```
Map<String, Date> inactiveDevices = service.getInactiveDevices();
for (String deviceToken : inactiveDevices.keySet()) {
    Date inactiveAsOf = inactiveDevices.get(deviceToken);
    ...
}
```